# Using conditional rules in a makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-compilation

I capture the intent of the Makefile in pseudo code, then indicate the issues I have. I'm looking for a Makefile which is more user friendly in a test environment. The correct usage of the Makefile is one of the below.

```
    make CATEGORY=parser TEST=basic.
    make ALL
```

If a user gives "JUST" the commands as indicated below, it should print a message saying "CATEGORY defined TEST undefined" and vice-versa

```
    make CATEGORY=parser
    make TEST=basic
```

I tried writing the Makefile in following ways, but it errors out:

```
    help:
        echo"Usage: make CATEGORY=<advanced|basic> TEST=<test-case>
        echo"       make ALL

    ifdef CATEGORY
        ifdef TEST
            CATEGORY_TEST_DEFINED = 1
        else
             echo "TEST not defined"
    else
        echo "CATEGORY not defined"
    endif



    ifeq ($(CATEGORY_TEST_DEFINED), 1)
    $(CATEGORY):
        cd $(PROJ)/$(CATEGORY)
        make -f test.mk $(TEST)
    endif

    ifdef ALL
    $(ALL):
         for i in `ls`
         cd $$(i)
         make all
    endif
```

The questions I have are:

1. Whether the rules in a Makefile can be selective (using ifdef to select the rules and targets).
2. echo doesn't work. echo should help the user with correct usage.

Comment: Following up on @Beta's point, you should look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially the section [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that `echo` belongs to the shell; Make can pass it to the shell in a command, but Make cannot execute it. Use `info` instead:

```
ifdef CATEGORY
$(info CATEGORY defined)
else
$(info CATEGORY undefined)
endif
```

If you want the rules to be conditional:

```
ifdef CATEGORY
ifdef TEST
$(CATEGORY):
    whatever
else
$(info TEST not defined)
else
$(info CATEGORY not defined)
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. If Make cannot execute shell command, then I have seen Makefiles having (indentation is difficult here) say for eg, hello: <next line with tab> @echo "Hello There". make hello outputs -> Hello There

Comment: @Mike: yes, in that case `echo` is in a command in the `hello` rule. When you "make hello", Make sends that command to the shell. If you want to do it that way, you must associate the "not defined" messages with some target, which seems untidy.

Answer (score 11):

The biggest issue here is that **all `ifdef`/`ifndef`/`ifeq`/... statements must be at column 0 or they it will results in an error**. The echo is a minor issue compared with the indentation issue.

Answer (score 4):

These lines are dubious:

```
help:
    echo"Usage: make CATEGORY=<advanced|basic> TEST=<test-case>
    echo"       make ALL
```

You need a space between `echo` and the string, and the string needs to be terminated:

```
help:
    echo "Usage: make CATEGORY=<advanced|basic> TEST=<test-case>"
    echo "       make ALL"
```

These lines are dubious:

```
ifdef CATEGORY
    ifdef TEST
        CATEGORY_TEST_DEFINED = 1
    else
         echo "TEST not defined"
else
    echo "CATEGORY not defined"
endif
```

Surely you need an `endif` before the second `else`?  (Even if it is not syntactically mandatory, I'd recommend it.)

```
ifdef CATEGORY
    ifdef TEST
        CATEGORY_TEST_DEFINED = 1
    else
         echo "TEST not defined"
    endif
else
    echo "CATEGORY not defined"
endif
```

Additionally, `make` only executes commands such as `echo` is supposed to be when processing a target (rule).  It won't execute `echo` there; it will simply object that you cannot define commands without them being actions for a target.  Despite everything that GNU Make adds to a makefile, the language in a makefile is a declarative language and not a procedural language.

---

Another way of handling this is to define default values for the macros:

```
CATEGORY = advanced
TEST     = all
```

Define default values that do something semi-reasonable; let the user override the default if they want to.  You can have a rule such as:

```
${CATEGORY}/${TEST}: ...dependencies...
    ...actions...
```

You can leave `help` as the first rule.  I have some directories where the first rule is:

```
null:
    @echo "You must specify a target with this makefile!"
```

This is equivalent to what you have (except that `make` does not echo the command before running it, so I only see the message instead of the echo command line and the message; that's the `@` at work).  The makefile this comes from also has a rule `all` which is otherwise usually the most sensible first (default) rule.